# How do I add the total the value of a range of cells, when they contain both numbers and letters?

Tags: excel-2010

for example my cell contains T 6.5 I want to look for all cells in a row that contain T and add the values of the numbers also contained in that cell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't mind a row beneath your data to help total things, I would suggest using the following as a quick solution.

Assuming that your data is in Row 1 (starting in cell A1), insert the below formula in Row 2 (cell A2) and copy it to the right as far as you have data in Row 1.

```
=IF(IFERROR(SEARCH("T ",A1),0)<>0,VALUE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"T ","")),0)
```

From there you can total the values across Row 2 using this:

```
=SUM(2:2)
```

Note that I assumed that there was a space after "T" in your example above and that this is explicitly included in the first formula above.  It simply strips that text from the cell and adds up the remaining numerical value IF the cells in Row 1 have a "T " in them.

Hope this helps or points you in the right direction.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example for row **#7**

```
Sub SumARow()
    Dim roww As Long, r As Range, _
        Zum As Double, v As Variant
    roww = 7
    For Each r In Cells(roww, 1).EntireRow.Cells
        v = CStr(r.Value)
        If InStr(1, v, "T") > 0 Then
            Zum = Zum + GetNumber(v)
        End If
    Next r
    MsgBox Zum
End Sub

Public Function GetNumber(s As Variant) As Double
    Dim msg As String, i As Long
    GetNumber = 0
    msg = ""
    For i = 1 To Len(s)
        ch = Mid(s, i, 1)
        If ch Like "[0-9]" Or ch = "." Then
            msg = msg & ch
        End If
    Next i
    If msg = "" Then Exit Function
    GetNumber = CDbl(msg)
End Function
```